# Gradle task not in expected location. How can I find it?

Tags: gradle

My ultimate goal is to have `:mymodule:assembleArm64debug` be dependent on other tasks that I've created. To add a dependsOn() to it, I need to find it first...

In Android Studio, when I press the Run button, in the build log I see:

```
Executing tasks: [:mymodule:assembleArm64Debug] in project path/to/my/project
```

So, I open up the mymodule build.gradle file and add this at the bottom (outside of dependencies {}, and I've also tried in the project-level build.gradle):

```
if (project.tasks.findByName(':mymodule:assembleArm64Debug')) {
    println "@me does exist"
} else {
    println "@me does NOT exist"
}
```

Sync and run again, and the log says:

```
@me does NOT exist
```

From the command line, I can see that it exists:

```
$ ./gradlew tasks

> ...
> :mymodule:assembleArm64Debug
> ...

$ ./gradle :mymodule:assembleArm64Debug
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 30s
```

So, it exists *somewhere*. How can I find its location so that I can use dependsOn() on it?

**Update**

After comments, I've also tried:

```
// mymodule build.gradle
if (tasks.findByName('assembleArm64Debug')) {
    println "@me assembleArm64Debug exists"
} else {
    println "@me assembleArm64Debug does NOT exist"
}
```

Prints: @me assembleArm64Debug does NOT exist

```
assembleArm64Debug {
    println "here"
}
```

Cannot run task because ERROR: Could not find method assembleArm64Debug() for arguments '' on project ':mymodule'

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a reference to a task named "assembleArm64Debug" in mymodule you can write, in the the mymodule `build.gradle` with the task:

```
tasks.findByName('assembleArm64Debug')
```

Note the plain name (not the path) doesn't have the colons. You can even just write:

```
assembleArm64Debug
```

since task objects are properties of the `Project` object in the Groovy script ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_build_script_primer.html#groovy:properties)).

In other project build.gradle files you can write:

```
tasks.findByPath(':mymodule:assembleArm64Debug')
```

...although there is the chance the task might not have been created at the time so I'd be cautious with that one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my question to include results from your recommendations. Unfortunately, they did not work.

Comment: You could try wrapping the calls in `afterEvaluate {}`. Maybe those tasks are getting added themselves in an `afterEvaluate` block.